Text-2-Sql using Llama3 locally
I'm attempting to utilize the template provided in the Langchain repository for text-to-SQL retrieval using Llama3. Here's the link to the template: Langchain SQL LlamaCPP Template.
Here is my code
# chain.py code

# Import necessary modules
import os
import re
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain_community.llms import LlamaCpp
from langchain_community.utilities import SQLDatabase
from langchain_core.output_parsers import StrOutputParser
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain_core.pydantic_v1 import BaseModel
from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableLambda, RunnablePassthrough, 
                                     RunnableParallel, RunnableMap

# Define model path and name
models_path = f'C:\\Users\\<my_username>\\Desktop\\SQL_LLAMACPP\\my-app\\packages\\sql- 
                 llamacpp\\model'
model_name_phi = 'Meta-Llama-3-8B.Q2_K.gguf'

# Instantiate LlamaCpp
llm_cpp = LlamaCpp(
                   model_path=f"{models_path}\\{model_name_phi}",
                   n_threds=4,
                   n_ctx=12048,
                   max_tokens=500,
                   top_p=1,
                   f16_kv=True,
                   verbose=True,
                  )

# Define PostgreSQL connection string and initialize SQLDatabase
CONNECTION_STRING = f"postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@127.0.0.1:5437/LLMs"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(CONNECTION_STRING,
                          schema="public",
                          view_support=True
                         )

 # Define functions to interact with the database
def get_schema(_):
    return db.get_table_info()

def get_query(query):
    sql_query = query.replace("SQLQuery: ", "")
    return sql_query

def run_query(query):
    return db.run(query)

 # Define prompt templates
sql_template = """
     You are a Postgres expert. Given an input question, first create a 
     syntactically correct Postgres query to run, then look at the results 
     of the query and return the answer to the input question.
     Unless the user specifies in the question a specific number of 
     examples to obtain, query for at most 5 results using the LIMIT clause 
     as per Postgres. You can order the results to return the most 
     informative data in the database.
     Never query for all columns from a table. You must query only the 
     columns that are needed to answer the question. Wrap each column name 
     in double quotes (") to denote them as delimited identifiers.
     Pay attention to use only the column names you can see in the tables 
     below. You can never make a query using columns that do not exist. Also, 
     make sure to which column is in which table.
    Pay attention to use date('now') function to get the current date, if the question 
    involves "today".
    If you can't find an answer return a query with a polite message.
    Ensure the query follows rules:
    - No INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE instructions.
    - No CREATE, ALTER, DROP instructions.
    - Only SELECT queries for data retrieval.
    Use the following exact format:
    Question: <Question here>
    SQLQuery: <SQL Query to run>
    SQLResult: <Result of the SQLQuery>
    Answer: <Final answer here>
    Only use the following tables and columns:
    {dbschema}
 """  # noqa: E501

final_template = """
    Based on the table schema below, question, sql query, and sql response, 
    write a natural language response:
    Schema: {dbschema}
    Question: {question}
    SQLQuery: {query}
    SQLResponse: {response}
"""  # noqa: E501

# Define conversation memory
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(return_messages=True)

# Define prompt chains
sql_chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(
    dbschema=get_schema,
    history=RunnableLambda(lambda x: memory.load_memory_variables(x)["history"]),
)
| ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
    [
        ("system", sql_template),
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="history"),
        ("human", "{question}"),
    ]
)
| llm_cpp.bind(stop=["\nSQLResult:"])
| StrOutputParser()
)

prompt_response = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
[
    ("system", final_template),
    ("human", "{question}")
   ]
 )

sql_response_memory = RunnablePassthrough.assign(output=sql_chain) | save

class InputType(BaseModel):
   question: str

chain = (
    RunnablePassthrough.assign(
    query=sql_response_memory
 ).with_types(
    input_type=InputType
)
| RunnablePassthrough.assign(
    dbschema=get_schema,
    response=RunnableLambda(lambda x: db.run(get_query(x["query"]))),
)
| prompt_response
| llm_cpp 
)

But, I am getting the following error:

| sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "20" | LINE 1: 20,5NUT" |         ^ | | [SQL: 20,5NUT"] | (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)

Do I need to modify the prompt template or the model is not good for this task?
